# AES - Generating a key and Loading it gives an Invalid Key Exception

Tags: java, android, cryptography, aes

I've been trying to get AES encryption and decryption working for some time in Java.  Unfortunately I haven't had much luck.  Right now I can generate a key in one method the code for which is shown

```
keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance();
keyGen.init(size, random);
SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();
AesKey = key.getEncoded();
```

To use the key I convert it back to a SecretKeySpec and attempt to encrypt the input bytes.  My code for encryption is shown below.

```
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(AesKey, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
return cipher.doFinal(input);
```

However, when I call the cipher.init line I get an InvalidKeyException.

Am I generating the key incorrectly?  Am I loading the key incorrectly?  Is it a combination?  I'm stuck on this so any insight would be appreciated.

## **Update**

So I didn't realize it, but the part that was calling the generate function was passing in an invalid size.  When I found that bit of the code and changed it to 256 everything works as it should.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer? Unanswered questions get deleted over time.

Comment: SecureRandom should *not* be seeded, and you should use the default constructor. This will use the system entropy pool for the seed, which is more secure than using a timestamp. There is an update to the Android API docs coming soon which will help make this clear. (I've edited your code to reflect these changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that was calling the generate function was passing an invalid size.  I thought that would be caught by the keyGen.generateKey() line but I was mistaken.  It didn't throw the error until I actually tried to use the key.  Changing the code that called the generate function so that size was 256 fixed the problem.